# Fibonacci or Lucas sequence and triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles, 3d, fibonacci-numbers, lucas-numbers

I'm not a mathematician by any stretch. I do not have any formulas to produce here. I am just wondering if you find this interesting as well and any opinion you have on this observation.

I was stargazing earlier and noticing all of the triangles in the sky and all the possible ways to make a triangle based on the number of stars (aka points on a plane).

Of course you must start with 3 stars (or points) to make one triangle. If you add one more star (or point) you now have 4 potential ways to make a triangle. Add another point and you get 10 possible ways. Add another point and you get 19 possible ways. Etc.

If I find the difference in the number of possible triangles with each new point added it is 3, 6, 9, 15, 24.... where like the Fibonacci sequence the last two integers are added together to get the next number in the sequence.

I just find this fascinating and wonder how it relates to the nature of reality. Of course adding potential triangles is a 2D exercise. Just something I'm chewing on.

Thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... Unfortunately, there's an error in your early calculations that throws off your later pattern. The number of triangles from $5$ pts is $20$, not $19$. In general, that number is the same as the number of ways to *choose $3$ pts from $n$ pts*; that is, it's "$n$, choose $3$", a value calculated by $$\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3\cdot2\cdot1}$$
("$n$, choose $m$" is called a [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).) Those specific values are also known as [tetrahedral numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_number).

Comment: @Blue A 3-stars comment !